# How can I change kiwi template text when creating a new test case?

Tags: django, kiwi-tcms

I would like to ask if it is possible to set a default email address in [CC to:] textarea when creating a new test case? 
Like this: [Default CC to email address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VU1mL.png)

Answer (score 1):

@cuijun,
your title asks about one thing and the question description is completely different thing. Please be consistent in what you are asking about!

> How can I change kiwi template text when creating a new test case

This is being tracked in https://github.com/kiwitcms/Kiwi/issues/957 and related to it is https://github.com/kiwitcms/Kiwi/issues/1076 so click the Subscribe button on those issues to follow their progress.

> is it possible to set a default email address in [CC to:] textarea when creating a new test case?
> Like this: Default CC to email address

Not at the moment! Components have *initial owner* and *initial QA contact* fields but nothing along the lines of **initial cc list** for any of the existing objects in the database.

If that is important to how you are using Kiwi TCMS then open a feature request at https://github.com/kiwitcms/Kiwi/issues/new/choose so it doesn't get forgotten.

Comment: I got it. Sorry for wrong copy question title. Thanks!